# Populate SQL column based on other rows

Tags: sql

Apologies if this question may have been posted somewhere else, though I have searched and could not find an answer. Basically I have the following table (there would be additional rows but these are the main ones);

```
emp_id | Name
-------------
   1      a
   1
   2      b
   2
   3      c
   4      d
   4
   4
```

As part of a select statement, I would need to add an additional column which populates the name, even in the case it isn't mentioned in the name column;

```
emp_id | Name | SortList
------------------------
  1       a        a
  1                a
  2       b        b
  2                b
  3       c        c
  4       d        d
  4       d        d
```

I have a feeling I may need to do another select statement as a column. But not sure how it would work. Also just to note, a GROUP BY wouldn't work as I would need to display all records.

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query to find Name if it's not specified.

```
select emp_id, Name, coalesce(name, (select min(Name) from tablename t2
                                     where t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id)) as SortList
from tablename t1
```

Note that this will work even if an emp_id has different Names on different rows.

Alternatively, do a self JOIN:

```
select t1.emp_id, t2.Name, t2.Name as SortList
from tablename t1
  join (select emp_id, Name from tablename
        where name is not null) t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
```

Comment: Thanks! The coalesce solution is what I was after, especially as its a lot more robust in dealing with different names. Looks like I have some reading to do on this function!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2045a/3)

```
SELECT t1.emp_id, t1.name, t2.name as "Sortlist"
FROM mytable t1
join 
(SELECT name, emp_id
 from mytable
 where name is not null) t2
ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
```

AFAIK this should work for any rdbms

Comment: I did not know that, sorry been writing a lot of jquery and php the last couple of weeks, it worked on the fiddle  so I just presumed it works in any rdmbs, edited it